# Webpack or Babel issue: "Uncaught (in promise) No plugins, nothing to do!"

Tags: javascript, webpack, promise, async-await, babeljs

So I have a rather complicated setup going on, and it has been very difficult to track down the problem. I spent half a day, and am nowhere near figuring it out.

I am making a library, that I then include into a different project. Everything was working out alright, until it didn't. All of a sudden I started getting these errors:

`Uncaught (in promise) No plugins, nothing to do!`

I was able to track it down to an `await` statement in one of my functions. 
What is strange, is that it's not the first await in the chain, but it is the first to be assigned to a `const`

To illustrate

```
async index() {
  onSomethingHappens(async () => await create())
}

async create() {
  return fetch()
}

async fetch() {
  console.log('before')
  const pass = await check() // this is exactly where it happens
  console.log('after')
}
```

It's soo weird!

My .babelrc (after trying anything and everything)

```
{
"presets": ["env", "es2015", "stage-0", "react", "flow"],
"plugins": [
"syntax-async-functions",
"syntax-async-generators",
//    "transform-async-to-generator",
"transform-regenerator",

["babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend", {
  "globals": ["Error", "Array"]
}],
"transform-object-rest-spread",
"transform-react-jsx",
"transform-runtime"
 ]
 }
```

babel-polyfill is provided by the project that I'm integrating my library into.

What is this mystery?

Comment: `onSomethingHappens(() => await create())` that'll fail, as the function isn't declared `async` - though, not sure what that has to do with the error you are getting

Comment: nope, that's just something i missed in my example. my code has it.